# Preprocessing like "#if defined" in PHP

Tags: php, web, compilation, conditional-statements, preprocessor

I have following question:

I am programming a SOAP Server application with PHP. But I have to do that in two different ways, one which is for external usage (for all people) and one that is just for an import. And the import application has just a little bit more possibilities, but else it is the same.

In C I would write something like this (using the preprocessor):

```
#ifdef INTERNAL
int funktion( int ok, double asdfg, const char *aaa){
#else
int funktion( int ok, double asdfg){
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

I know the function `defined()` in PHP, but it does not really do what I want to do (I think).
But is there something simolar?

Of course I could write two different applications, but it would be very great if there was something like this ...

Thank you for help!

EDIT:
I know that normally it is possible to write conditional functions like

```
if(CST){
     function asdf($asdf){
     }
}
else{
    function asdf(){}
}
```

but I need it in a Class and there it does not work ...

Kind regards!

Comment: PHP is not a compiled language. There are no such compiler directives. But could you explain your need? Is it really to decide whether to have the 3rd argument or not? If so, that can be solved differently.

Comment: Well, I know that php is not compiled. But I hoped, that there are some workarounds ...

It is need for something like this:
For _normal_ users e.g. the `function add()` has 3 Parameters, but for the import I need the database ID too. And in the function I need to build the SQL statement. Normally, the ID is auto_incremented, but if it is given ...

"If so, that can be solved differently"
With optional parameters (like `function add($test,$test2,$asdf=NULL)`?
I know, but that is not what I need, because the normal user MUST NOT use the third parameter ...

But thank you for your help!

Comment: No, I was not thinking optional arguments. You can define a function conditionally, and so in two different signatures depending on that condition.

Comment: Ähm, but not inside a class I think ...     

But thank you very much!

Comment: If you are looking for a solution with class methods, could you specify that requirement in your question?

Comment: Yes, I did not think that it would get neccessary. Sorry!

Comment: Follow a factory method there to select the context depending on your defined variable.... and in that contexts write different functions.

Comment: you can coniditionaly declare whole classes but for sure not methods. You can also extend main class and conditionaly declare subclass which will use traits to injects method you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP there are no such pre-processing constructs as PHP is not compiled. But in PHP classes can be defined conditionally. So you could do this in two steps:

1. define the class with the full option (3rd argument), but define those sensitive members as `protected` instead of `public`
2. extend the class conditionally, providing access to the `protected` members via a new name, and with the appropriate signature. Other `public` members do not have to be mentioned explicitly as they are inherited as usual

Here is an example:

```
define('INTERNAL', false);

// Define complete class, but with members set to protected
// when they have constraints depending on INT/EXT access
class _myClass {
    protected function _funktion ($ok, $str, $id = -1) {
        echo  "arguments: $ok,$str,$id";
    }
    public function otherFunc() {
        echo "other func";
    }
}

// Define myClass conditionally
if (INTERNAL) {
    class myClass extends _myClass{
        // give public access to protected inherited method 
        public function funktion ($ok, $str, $id) {
            $this->_funktion ($ok, $str, $id);
        }
    }
} else {
    class myClass extends _myClass{
        // give public access to protected inherited method, but only
        // with 2 parameters
        function funktion ($ok, $str) {
            $this->_funktion ($ok, $str);
        }
    }
}


$obj = new myClass();

// if signature has 2 arguments, third is ignored 
$obj->funktion(1, 'test', 3);
// other methods are availble 
$obj->otherFunc();
```

Comment: Yes. I mean, it is not really the solution I wanted to see, but it seem to be the only possible ...     
Thank you for all!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, and a little different, but FWIW I was looking for some more elegant way, than the one I use now, to have a debug/release run, i.e. a kind of conditional compilation.

So far I couldn't find anything better than running some code inside the `assert` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php). Here's one of possible use cases:

```
function debugMsg(string $message): bool
{
    echo $message . PHP_EOL;

    return true;
}

.....
assert(debugMsg("some debug message"));
```

Then I can conditionally set `'zend.assertions'` to `'0'` for release or to `'1'` for debug (using `ini_set`).

As a result, having a very heavy processing (performance test) and running the code in the "debug mode", gives me tons of output and allows me to see lots of details for debugging purpose, but it works up to 10 times slower than in the "release mode" with all that logging skipped.

Note:

- that code (the function call) should return true to work correctly
- the `'zend.assertions'` shouldn't be `'-1'` in the `php.ini`, because otherwise the code for `assert` is not even generated for execution, and thus cannot be controlled inside the code.